# How to Connect mongodb in node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nodejs-server

I tried to connect mongodb in node js.but its throwing this type error.

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb mongodb:27017
```

How to fix it.any one can give me solution

index.js

const MongoClie

```
nt = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID
const url = "mongodb://olcadmin:olcmongodb@mongodb:27017/admin";
const client = new MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true },function(err,db)
{
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(err)
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Connected Sucessfully")
    }
});


Connected Successfully
```

but I got This type error:

```
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb mongodb:27017
    at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'mongodb',
  host: 'mongodb',
  port: 27017 }
```

Comment: Is there a locally resolve host named `mongodb`?

Comment: The URL address is somewhat wrong

Comment: To add more detalis to what Sirko mentioned, you should have a line that looks like `127.0.0.1 mongodb` in your `/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try `"mongodb://olcadmin:olcmongodb@127.0.0.1:27017/admin"` instead of `"mongodb://olcadmin:olcmongodb@mongodb:27017/admin"`, if you are using local mongodb